# Efficiently execute 100K update statements - C# & Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

My C# application retrieves over a million records from Sql Server, processes them and then updates the database back. This results in close to 100,000 update statements and they all have the following form -

```
update Table1 set Col1 = <some number> where Id in (n1, n2, n3....upto n200)
```

"Id" is an int, primary key with clustered index. No two update statements update the same Ids, so in theory, they can all run in parallel without any locks. Therefore, ideally, I suppose I should run as many as possible in parallel. The expectation is that all finish in no more than 5 minutes.

Now, my question is what is the most efficient way of doing it? I'm trying the below -

1. Running them sequentially one by one - This is the least efficient solution. Takes over an hour.
2. Running them in parallel by launching each update in it's on thread - Again very inefficient because we're creating thousands of threads but I tried anyway and it took over an hour and quite a few of them failed because of this or that connection issue.
3. Bulk inserting in a new table and then do a join for the update. But then we run into concurrency issues because more than one user are expected to be doing it.
4. Merge batches instead of updates - Google says that merge is actually slower than individual update statements so I haven't tried it.

I suppose this must be a very common problem with many applications out there that handle a sizeable amounts of data. Are there any standard solutions? Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635796/bulk-update-in-c-sharp

Comment: Instead of creating thousands of threads, have you considered using the thread pool?

Comment: You want to do a execute a batch of requests.

Comment: (3) is the way to do it.  If concurrency is a problem, then break them into smaller batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a integer tbl type so that I can pass all my id's to sp as a list and then single query will update whole table.

This is still slow but i see this is way more quicker than conventional "where id in (1,2,3)"

**definition for TYPE**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[integer_list_tbltype] AS TABLE(
    [n] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [n] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

**Here is the usage.**

```
declare @intval integer_list_tbltype
declare @colval int=10

update c
set c.Col1=@colval
from @intval i
join Table1 c on c.ID = i.n
```

Let me know if you have any questions.