# How to update Bulk Data in sql Server from C# List

Tags: c#

I have a List of multiple data(20000 Records),I  have insert and update the List from C# to SQL server database.

I have already used Z.EntityFramework.ExtensionMethods but it is paid.
SqlBulkCopy is working in Case of Insert only,how to update the dataTable from the List.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635796/bulk-update-in-c-sharp) one

Comment: MS Sql I guess. Create a stored proc with a table-valued parameter and pass the list .

Comment: Please provide some code to accompany your question...

Comment: `I have already used Z.EntityFramework.ExtensionMethods but it is paid` What do you mean by this?

Comment: Means Its 3rd party Tool , which paid.

Comment: Please give me any Suggestions..